# "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" error when searching for tweets using the Twitter API

Tags: laravel, twitter, oauth

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to search for tweets and then save them in a database. For this project I'm using Laravel and [TwitterOAuth](https://packagist.org/packages/abraham/twitteroauth).

Here's the **code:**

```
class TwitterController extends BaseController
{
public function test() {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth('',
        '',
        '',
        '');
    $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

    $tweets = $connection->get('search/tweets',
        ['q' => "cryptocurrency"]);

    foreach($tweets as $tweet) {



        $tweet_id = $tweet[0]->id;
        $oembed_j = file_get_contents('https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https://twitter.com/x/status/' . $tweet_id);
        $oembed = json_decode($oembed_j);

        $twitter = new Twitter;
        $twitter->url = $oembed->url;
        $twitter->author_name = $oembed->author_name;
        $twitter->author_url = $oembed->author_url;
        $twitter->html = $oembed->html;
        $twitter->width = $oembed->width;
        $twitter->height = $oembed->height;
        $twitter->type = $oembed->type;
        $twitter->cache_age = $oembed->cache_age;
        $twitter->provider_name = $oembed->provider_name;
        $twitter->provider_url = $oembed->provider_url;
        $twitter->version = $oembed->version;
        $twitter->save();
    }
}
```

}

and the **error:**

```
"(1/1) FatalErrorException
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

in TwitterController.php (line 27)"
```

Comment: please highlight line 27. I am guessing it is this one ` foreach($tweets as $tweet) {` so the errors says that $tweets is not an array, so maybe you are looping the wrong way

Comment: Please show the results of `dd($tweets);` inserted right before `foreach` clause

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin dd($tweets) results in: {#167 ▼
  +"statuses": array:15 [▶]
  +"search_metadata": {#495 ▶}
}

Comment: @TimoGüntner you need to expand the list and post it in your question. In this case, we'll be able to help you. Or maybe make a screenshot if the object is not too big.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Whoops, sorry forgot that. Here's a pastebin with most of them expanded: https://pastebin.com/YkSF0YkH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$tweets` is an object with `statuses` property you need to iterate over it like this:

```
foreach ($tweets->statuses as $tweet)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But now I have another problem with the html of the tweet when I try to insert it into the DB: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x81 ...' for column 'html' at row 1